# Clear graphics/rectangle without changing colour?

Tags: c#, winforms, background, gdi, rectangles

I'm drawing a rectangle onto a `Panel` object (PanelArea) using the following code:

```
    private void GenerateGraphic()
    {
        Graphics RandomArea = PanelArea.CreateGraphics();
        RandomArea.Clear(Color.Beige);
        SolidBrush Brush1 = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128,220,20,60));
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        //Offset is from the top left hand corner.
        rect.X = 25;
        rect.Y = 25;
        rect.Width = 1;
        rect.Height = 1;
        rect.Inflate(XArea / 2, YArea / 2);
        RandomArea.FillRectangle(Brush1, rect);
    }
```

I'm setting the `BackgroundImage` of the `Panel` to a snippet of the screen.

I'd like to be able to keep the background image, whilst resetting the rectangle for it to be resized.

I need `RandomArea.Clear(Color.Beige)` to reset the graphics in order to remove the previous rectangle. The snag is though, is that this places the colour over the background image of the panel.

How can I clear the graphics area/rectangle each time, whilst still being able to view a background image for the `Panel`?

Comment: Can't you Clear(Color.Transparent)? - Of course you really should not draw like this anyway! Use the Paint event instead and call PanelArea.Invalidate(); this way the background will always be empty..

Comment: Doesn't work - the background just appears black.

Comment: Are you doing all your drawing from OnPaint()?

Comment: I'm calling it when I change values in `NumericUpDown` boxes.

Comment: If you don't do all your drawing from OnPaint(), you're in for a world of pain. What happens right now if you resize or minimise and restore your application? Does it still look correct?

Comment: Sorry my mistake! I am using the `OnPaint()` in addition to the former.

Additionally, I believe the `Invalidate()` method has solved my problem, thanks!